# CSS is not linked to HTML(template) file successfully and nothing happens when I change the CSS - Django

Tags: python, django

I just finished reading Django document and I'm trying to deploy a website with it.

I linked all the style sheets to HTML file(template) but when I change the CSS file(like changing color), nothing change. Furthermore the pre loader don't work and Its just spinning.

Directory Structure:

[image: The directory]

**HTML file header**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/basic.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/layout.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blogs.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/line-awesome.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/simplebar.css' %}" />
```

**views.py:**

```
def home(request):

    return render(request, "index.html")
```

**setting.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

And for the preloader:

**HTML file:**

```
<div class="preloader">
   <div class="centrize full-width">
      <div class="vertical-center">
         <div class="spinner">
            <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
            <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
   var preload = $('.preloader');
   var lines = $('.lines-grid');
   preload.find('.spinner').fadeOut(function(){
      preload.fadeOut();
      lines.addClass('loaded');
   });
});
```

I tried to delete the pre loader but when I delete the JS or the html element the page goes black at all

Comment: Browsers typically do not reload the css on each page.  In normal web usage, a site's CSS files will remain unchanged from one page to the next, so browsers keep a local cache copy to reduce network traffic, and only update the cache once a day.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/118884/494134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your static files are loaded and when you make a change, you need to reset your browser cache. For this, you need to press the Ctrl + F5.
Sometimes you may need to run the project again, especially when you edit your settings.py file

Comment: E!. Che tasadofi ostad XD.
Doraton ro dashtam mididam be in moshklel khordam. Dashtam ye qaleb jadid mizadam.
Kheyli momnone azaton fek mikonam moshkel hal shod.

Comment: Salam kiarash, story shod tasadofemoon